# Question on Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, lattice-orders, nonclassical-logic

Consider the following (complete and distributive) three-element lattice $\mathbf{A}_3= \langle \{1,a,0\}, \wedge, \vee, \Rightarrow, ^*,1, 0 \rangle$ where $1^*=0, a^*=1, 0=1^*$ and $x \Rightarrow y = (x^* \vee y)$ for any $x,y \in \{1,a,0\}$. So ($1\Rightarrow a) = a$ and $(1\Rightarrow 0)= 0 $ and for the rest of elements $\Rightarrow$ always receives value $1$. Also the set of designated values is $\{1,a\}$

Question 1. Is this a well-known logic? If yes could someone please give me some bibliography references?

Question 2. Does there exist some propositional formula that allows me to "distinguish" the element $a$ from $0$ ? For instance, I can distinguish 1 and 0 in the sense that if I set $v(p)=1$, then  $v(p \wedge \neg \neg p )$ is in the set of designated elements, however, for $v(p)=0$,  $v(p \wedge \neg \neg p )$ is  not in the set of designated elements.

Comment: Ad 1: This is very similar to the three-valued logic system developped by Łukasiewicz in 1920, sometimes called Ł3, the first-ever formal multi-valued logic system. The only difference between his system and what you propose is that in Ł3 $(a \implies 0) = a$. Your star operator would be Łukasiewicz's modal operator of possiblity.

Comment: What definition of lattice are you using? The usual definitions don't have $\Rightarrow$ and $^*$ in the signature (or $1$ and $0$, but they exist automatically in a finite lattice). Under the usual definition, there is only one lattice with three elements.

Comment: @RobArthan -- I'm guessing he uses the standard definition of lattices and it is in fact *the* lattice with 3 elements, it's just that he imbues it with additional operations $*$ and $\implies$

Comment: @MichałZapała: maybe you are right, but in Łukasiewicz's $3$-valued logic, the primitive binary operations of disjunction and conjunction are not the lattice meet and join. I think the OP should clarify the question.

Comment: @RobArthan, are you certain? They look exactly like meet and join to me.

Comment: If $a$ is the "middle" value in Łukasiewicz's  $3$-valued logic and I write $\oplus$ for the primitive (or strong)  disjunction, you have $a \oplus a = 1$. (I am using the notation and terminology of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Łukasiewicz_logic.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! However, is there a way to define the strong disjunction in terms of the meet, join,  conditional and complement ?

Comment: Yes, but if $a^*$ is the complement of $a$, you will get $a^* =a $, not $a* = 1$.